# Laravel - How can I order a query by a field in an eager loaded polymorphic relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have a polymorphic relationship setup between users and contractors:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->morphs('user');
});

Schema::create('contractors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    //... etc
});
```

**App\User**

```
public function userable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**App\Contractor**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'userable');
}
```

The goal is to have different user types as a contractor may have other field data we need to collect but they will always have all of the fields in the users table.

The problem I'm having is when getting all of the Contractors and eager loading the User data, how can I order by the last_name column in the users table?

```
class ContractorController extends Controller
{
    public function all(Request $request)
    {
        return Contractor::with('user')->paginate(15); // order by users.last_name here
    }
}
```

I've read that I'll have to join the tables, but for some reason that is returning NULL for the user object in the response.

```
class ContractorController extends Controller
{
    public function all(Request $request)
    {
        return Contractor::with('user')
            ->join('users', 'contractors.id', '=', 'users.userable_id')
            ->paginate(15);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `lastname` is the column of users table. you cannot use `with('user')` and order by `lastname`.

However, you can use `join('users',...)` instead of `with(user)`:

```php
Contractor::join('users', 'contractors.id', '=', 'users.userable_id')
          ->orderBy('users.lastname')
          ->paginate(15);
```

And because there are duplicated `id(contractors.id, users.id)` when you use `join`, if you still want to get the `user` object as the attribute, you can do it like this:

```php
Contractor::join('users', 'contractors.id', '=', 'users.userable_id')
          ->orderBy('users.lastname')
          ->selectRaw('contractors.*, users.lastname')
          ->with('user')
          ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Using joins instead of eager loaded fixed a couple of other issues I was having as well and made the result set much more understandable on the frontend. This was the way to go for me. Thanks!